# Always visible view in Android

Tags: android

In iOS we can add subviews to UINavigationController view which will always stay visible across the application and do not slide with the views when they are pushed/popped.

I am trying to accomplish the same thing in Android but cannot see a way to do this. I've seen solutions like adding the view to every Activity but that does not give me the result I want.

What I am trying to do is to add an image for the footer which always is on the bottom across the application and does not slide with the activities when they are transitioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Android navigation approach is based on using `Fragments` inside a single host `Activity`. This gives you the possibility to use the `Activity` as a container for multiple `Fragments`. Usually `Fragments` will take all `Activity` space, but in your case you can leave some place for views that should remain visible during the whole application lifecycle and use remaining space as the container for `Fragments`. Hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Yes, and just define the sliding animation for transitions between "non blocked" `Fragments` to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any tutorial/documentation of how to use this?

Comment: And Is this supported in 2.2 (API 8)?

Comment: @Bms270, I would recommend you this tutorial on Fragments: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/
Just play around with the Activity layout to achieve the desired effect.